# issue with the responsiveness of navigation bar at class navbar-expand-md

Tags: html

i am creating a navbar in bootstrap and the issue is that when i resize my browser it shows navigation toggle button and if the page is inspected in chrome or opera navigation toggle button is not shown and full menu is displayed.
i uploaded the site on a domain and looked it from a phone but there was no toggle button and simply complete nav menu.
my issue's screenshots link is http://zian.tk/pictures/Capture01.jpg

HTML for the code is:

```
<nav class="nav navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="row w-100">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h1`enter code here` class="text-white text-center">
            LOGO
            </h1>
        </div> 
        <button class="navbar-toggler w-100" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button> 
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center mx-auto justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-centre mt-2" >
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown pr-4">
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                         <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-item">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-item">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-item">blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-item">Insights</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-item">contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link  dropdown-item">Services</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 pt-3 float-right justify-content-end ">
            <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="pr-2 mb-0"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook pr-2 mb-0"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-instagram pr-2 mb-0"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-behance pr-2 mb-0"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-google pr-2 mb-0"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please use Stack Overflow's image server, not an external site to store images. Upload an image by clicking the image icon in the action-bar above the text entry area while editing or drag-and-drop the image. Please [edit] your question to do this. That way your question does not rely on an external link, which may die at some point and make your question useless/less useful for future visitors. Due to licensing restrictions, we probably can't do it for you (depends on the license for the site you chose; I'm not going to take the time to check).

Comment: Do you have viewport meta tag defined in your html?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Thanks alot issue solved i was missing <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">